# British English word stress in sentence

Tags: british-english, stress

Where should I put stress in the sentence below?

> If only I knew who it was from

Comment: The stress could be placed on any of the eight words, depending on which one you wanted to emphasise.

Comment: We need more context. Something like "I've had a Valentine's card. If only I knew who it was from! I'm dying with excitement." or "Someone's sent me a poison-pen letter. If only I knew who it was from: I'd knock their lights out!" The stress in those examples is different. Please add your context.

Comment: Although I agree with WS2 and Andrew Leach's comments, I think there's a natural stress on *only*. Consider Andrew's *Valentine's card* example. The preamble tends to place the primary stress on *who*, but the natural cadence places a small stress on *only* as well.

Comment: @Lawrence Saying the Valentine’s card example card example out loud and not giving any extra prominence to any part of the sentence that would require additional context to justify, I count three primarily stressed words: in descending order of stress prominence: _Valentine’s_, _from_, _only_. I wouldn’t stress _who(m)_ unless I had some contextual reason to.

Comment: Why is this marked "British"? I cannot help but wonder where the language of Her Majesty’s Queendom enters into this question, as opposed to the language the rest of us all speak. :)

Comment: @WS2 Yes, but most of those would inolve *marked* stress.

Comment: An unmarked version of the sentence would be likely to have stress on the words *only*, *knew*, *who* and *from*. The words *if, I, it, was* are very unlikely to be stressed in an unmarked version of the sentence. For our purposes you can think of a marked version of the sentence as one containing contrastive stress or one where some of the material has already been mentioned.

Comment: @Araucaria Thanks for pointing that out. Not being a linguistician, I was unaware of the distinction between marked and unmarked stress. Though I had heard about marked and unmarked *received pronunciation*.

Answer (score 4):

From my unpublished play *The Kidnapped Goat*. Dramatis personae:

> Police Detective
> Mysterious Man

Act I, Scene I, the Police Detectives, holding a blood-stained sheet of notepaper in his hand, inquires of the Mysterious Man about a kidnapping.

> **Police Detective (*to the Mysterious Man*):** We can solve this case only with your help since you're the only one who knows who sent the ransom note.
>
> **Mysterious Man:** Ah, but that would be true **if** only I knew who it was from. It's possible you're mistaken: there may be other who can help you, and I may not be able to.
>
> **Police Detective**: Do you mean you know who sent the note but decline to help us or do you mean you don't know anything helpful?
>
> **Mysterious Man**: If **only** I knew who it was from, then I could help, but I don't know, so I can't.
>
> **Police Detective**: Then we're at an impasse.
>
> **Mysterious Man:** That would be true if only **I** knew who it was  from, but there are others.
>
> **Police Detective**: How about giving us an educated guess?
>
> **Mysterious Man**: If only I **knew** who it was from would I help. Guessing will do more harm than good.
>
> **Police Detective** (holding up the paper): Can you tell us anything at all about this note?
>
> **Mysterious Man**: If only I knew **who** it was from could I tell you more, say about where it was mailed from or the motives of the kidnappers.
>
> **Police Detective**: We have had several ransom notes, but you'll see that this one is bloodstained, which worries us.  Can you tell us about the other notes?
>
> **Mysterious Man**: If only I knew who **it** (*gesturing to the note  in the Police Detective's hand*) was from could I tell you about the others.
>
> **Police Detective**: We expect more notes from the kidnappers.
>
> **Mysterious Man**: If only I knew who it (*again gesturing to the blood-stained note*) **was** from could I tell you about who will send further notes.
>
> **Police Detective**: This note arrived at its final destination after having been passed though several intermediaries. Does that tell you anything?
>
> **Mysterious Man**: If only I knew who it was **from** could I tell you anything about the route it took.

*The lights go out; a shot is heard; a voice heretofore unheard shouts, "What's all this then?"*

*Curtain.*

Comment: +1 But ... the *only* in your first example is modifying the word *I* and means something like *not apart from* , but in OP's sentence it is arguably modifying the whole clause and has a different meaning.

Comment: @Araucaria Everybody's a critic. No wonder I can't get this play produced.

Comment: I'd produce one of your longer works - only you wouldn't want me to because I'd be a rubbish  producer ...